# WOOCOOMERCE: Run function before payment gateway (paying)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In WooCommerce I create orders and users by code and on the 'order-pay' endpoint a user is created by form + ajax. The 'proceed to checkout' button is disabled by jQuery until the user is created. Now I want to create a server side check. So trying to run a function after submit but before the redirect to the payment gateway.

I've tried these hooks but they all don't work for me in this case (do nothing).

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_process', 'is_user_created' , 1, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'is_user_created' , 1, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'is_user_created' , 1, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'is_user_created' , 1, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'is_user_created' , 1, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', 'is_user_created' , 1, 1 );
```

The function used to test is:

```
function is_user_created( $order_id ){
    die ('No account created');
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is it so hard to find a list of woocommerce hooks per page or sequence of execution or order > payment flow?

Anyway, after hours and hours of searching:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_pay_action', 'Your Function', 1, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks, searched a lot for this too...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_process', 'fireBeforeCheckout', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best hook that u can use, this hook launch after last checkout process before redirect user to payment gateway (paying)

`add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed',  'callback_function' );`